# passing param to asyncio.run() function via command line

Tags: python

I'm kinda new to Python
I would like to ask how can I pass a param to the async function via commandline

```
async def main(action):
    async with TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        time = get_time()
        if action == 'in':
            message = "It's " + time + ". Time to work."
        else:
            message = "It's " + time + ". Let's call it a day."

        await client.send_message('me', message)
asyncio.run(main(WHAT_SHOULD_I_USE_HERE_OTHER_THAN_input()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

argparse is the way to go
https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

minimum example:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('--argument', metavar='N', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

and then use `python script.py --argument my_argument`. `args.argument` will be the string 'my_argument'.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Btw,  I myself also found another solution which is using the getopt and the line is now `asyncio.run(main(getopt.getopt([action], [action])))` and inside the command line i will just input `python app.py in` to get the result.

Comment: @TimothyGoh but try to stick with ArgumentParser though since it would work on non -nix system as well.and it is cleaner and can be expanded in future.